# Log client request without waiting for server response

Tags: logging, nginx

I am using nginx's access log to log client request.

Configuration I have used is below:

```
http {
    log_format keep_log '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                           '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                           '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';

    server {
        gzip on;
        access_log /var/logs/nginx/access.log keep_log;
        ...
    }
}
```

Nginx does keep the access log perfectly but the problem is, the server I am using behind nginx taking too much time to response back to the client. So nginx waiting for the server to response back and then when server send the response, nginx add the log with status code.

Is there any way to keep log as soon as client make a request to nginx without waiting for the backend server response?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible even in theory, since part of the fields in your log is unknown by that time.